# Significato di "imposte cieche"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Gli occhiali d'oro*, di Giorgio Bassani, ho letto:

> Camminammo affiancati a passo più lento  verso il Montagnone. Mezzanotte era suonata da un pezzo, e per le strade non si incontrava nessuno. File e file di **imposte** chiuse e **cieche**, porte sprangate, e, a intervalli, le luci quasi subacquee dei lampioni.

Cercando il vocabolo "cieco" in alcuni dizionari, ho pensato che "imposte cieche" fossero imposte posizionate in modo da lasciar la stanza al buio, ma non riesco a capire perché si parla di "imposte chiuse e cieche": c'è qualche differenza tra "imposte chiuse" e "imposte cieche"? Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "imposte cieche"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le imposte chiuse nel passo da te citato penso si riferisca al fatto che non erano spalancate ai lati della finestra.

Le imposte cieche si riferisco al cosiddetto scuro o anta cieca delle finestre che servono effettivamente per lasciare la stanza al buio.

[Da una rivista specializzata nel settore arredamento](https://www.cosedicasa.com/ristrutturare/finestre/tapparelle-persiane/cambiare-imposte-o-persiane-48087):

> Sin dai più antichi sistemi costruttivi, le imposte sono state una
>   soluzione per conferire alla casa un po’ di protezione dagli agenti
>   atmosferici e al tempo stesso di riservatezza. Cominciamo subito col
>   dire che per questo elemento architettonico esistono molti nomi:
>   persiane, imposte, griglie, scuri, antoni o ante esterne… Tutti modi
>   differenti di identificare una funzione fondamentale – l’oscuramento e
>   la protezione di un’apertura nel muro esterno – declinata nelle sue
>   svariate interpretazioni.
>
> Le imposte si suddividono in due tipologie fondamentali: **lo scuro o
>   anta cieca** che senza feritoie non lascia passare luce e può essere
>   tutta liscia oppure più spesso a doghe orizzontali o verticali; la
>   persiana, anch’essa a sua volta presente in numerose diverse fatture
>   ma perlopiù composta da una serie di lamelle (stecche) orizzontali che
>   lasciano passare un po’ di luce. Anche la persiana può essere di
>   diversi tipi: **con lamella fissa chiusa (che quindi rende l’anta cieca**)
>   a singola o doppia spiovenza; con lamella aperta di forma trapezoidale
>   (“tipo antico”), con lamella stondata (più moderno); o ancora con
>   lamella orientabile mediante un meccanismo che consente di far ruotare
>   la lamella in modo tale che si possa regolare il passaggio della luce.

Ed ancora:

> Imposte cieche che, applicate alla parte interna delle finestre,
>   consentono l'oscuramento dell'ambiente e migliorano la sicurezza
>   contro le effrazioni (Devoto-Oli, 1972).